# Python not recognizing the greater than sign?

Tags: python, batch-file, unicode

I am using Python to create windows commands using `subprocess.call(command)` where `command` is a string I've generated for the Windows command.  I need the results of my command to output to a `.txt` file so I use `2>> C:\Users\me\out.txt` as part of `command` except Python does not seem to recognize the greater than character, `>`.  I've tried using the Unicode value, `u'\u003E'` too.

[EDIT] If I copy `command` and paste it into my command prompt, then it will execute the command properly.  Otherwise it won't work from my Python script.

Comment: How exactly are you doing this in code?

Comment: `>` is processed by the shell. Are you using `shell=True` in the call?

Answer (score 1):

Python has nothing to do with that.

If you do

```
subprocess.call("command 2>>out.txt", shell=True)
```

it is the shell which does this part of redirection.

If you don't work with the shell, it cannot work. In this case, you better do

```
with open("out.txt", "a") as outfile:
    subprocess.call(["command"], stderr=outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shell constructs such as redirection, you need the parameter `shell=True`.